# When inet_pton fails but getaddrinfo succeeds?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

In a legacy code base, I saw the following workflow.

Given a `host`(i.e `const char*`), step one is to use `inet_pton` to convert `host` to `ip`(i.e. `uint32_t`). In the case of failure, it processes step two which is to use `getaddrinfo` to retrieve the `ip`(i.e. sockaddr_in::sin_addr::s_addr).

**Question**> Can someone give me one example where the inet_pton fails(i.e. return != 1) while getaddrinfo succeeds?

Comment: inet_pton works "172.217.12.196" but "www.google.com".
inet_pton(),
converts an IP address in numbers-and-dots notation into either a struct in_addr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone give me one example where the inet_pton fails(i.e. return != 1) while getaddrinfo succeeds?

`inet_pton()` converts an *IP address* expressed in string form to an address structure.

`getaddrinfo()` can do the same (as also `gethostbyname()` can do), but it can also look up a host *name* to get an address, and fill the address info structure with the result. `getaddrinfo()` does some other work too.

Thus, `inet_pton()` will fail if you give it a string expressing a hostname, say `"stackoverflow.com"`, but `gethostbyname()` may well succeed for such an input.

> Given a `host`(i.e `const char*`), step one is to use `inet_pton` to convert
> `hos`t to `ip`(i.e. `uint32_t`). In the case of failure, it processes step
> two which is to use `getaddrinfo` to retrieve the `ip`

This sounds like it was intended to allow machines to be specified either by IP address or by name, by someone who did not appreciate that `getaddrinfo()` could handle both.  The call to `getaddrinfo()` might have been a call to `gethostbyname()` in some earlier version of the software, which would have explained such a confusion better.

Or possibly the idea was to optimize the path where the machine is identified by an IP number, on the assumption that `inet_pton()` was substantially cheaper than `getaddrinfo()`.

Either way, I would be inclined to instead just go straight to `getaddrinfo()`, without trying `inet_pton()`.

Answer (score 0):

From man `inet_pton`:

> **RETURN VALUE**
> inet_pton() returns 1 on success (network address was successfully converted).  0 is returned if src does not contain a character string representing a valid network address in the specified address family.  If af does not contain a valid address family, -1 is returned and errno is set to EAFNOSUPPORT.

It's easy to see when `inet_pton` could possibly fail, whereas `getaddrinfo` has a lot more, 'fine-grained' (negative) return values (see man getaddrinfo).

`getaddrinfo` is just a more convenient way to retrieve a socket address.

From the man page of `getaddrinfo`:

> **DESCRIPTION**
> ...
> The getaddrinfo() function combines the functionality provided by the gethostbyname(3) and getservbyname(3) functions into a single interface, but unlike the latter functions, getaddrinfo() is reentrant and allows programs to eliminate IPv4-versus-IPv6 dependencies.